# How to Switch Drives of Mass Shortcuts?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder full of shortcuts leading to `F:` recently due to complications I cannot use the `F:` drive and it now resides in `D:`. There are about 100+ shortcuts in the folder, is there anyway to change them in mass? I'd prefer using Batch for this but using external programs will work just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could done with free tool **Xchang32.exe** from **Clay's Utilities
for Win32** which of course can be also used on Windows x64.

Download ClaysUtils32.zip and extract from ZIP archive `Xchang32.exe` into folder with the shortcut files.

**Important note:** Clay Ruth, author of **Xchang32.exe** and owner of domain `clayruth.com` died years ago. For that reason the ZIP file with this tool is not available anymore in world wide web although it was permitted explicitly to distribute this package free of charge according to read me file in the ZIP file.

Run the following two commands:

```
xchang32.exe /i *.lnk "F:^x5C" "D:^x5C"
xchang32.exe /i *.lnk "F^x00:^x00^x5C" "D^x00:^x00^x5C"
```

The first line replaces case-insensitive all `F:\` by `D:\` in ASCII in any *.lnk file in current directory.

The second line replaces case-insensitive all `F:\` by `D:\` in Unicode as shortcut files usually contain file and directory paths in ASCII/ANSI as well as in Unicode.

Note: This quick solution could modify also binary data streams with `46 3A 5C` or `66 3A 5C` or `46 00 3A 00 5C` or `66 00 3A 00 5C` in the *.lnk files which do not belong to a directory or file path. But I suppose those byte sequences do not exist in binary data of the shortcut files.

Comment: Those sequences can occur in the binary data. For example, there are file sizes and timestamps in the shortcut file, which might happen to have those sequences if you are unlucky.